# Swagger yaml (openapi-3.0) upload files does not work

Tags: file-upload, swagger-ui, openapi

I am using openapi 3.0 to write the swagger yaml file. But upload files feature doesnot work. the swagger ui does not display the upload button as expected. below is my swagger yaml code snippet. Can someone help to take a look? Thanks!!!

```
/uploadfiles:
    post:
      requestBody:
        content:
          multipart/form-data:
            schema:
              required:
              - file_list
              - statement_terminator
              properties:
                statement_terminator:
                  type: string
                default_schema:
                  type: string
                encoding_type:
                  type: string
                file_list:
                  type: array
                  items:
                    type: string
                    format: binary
        required: true
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `type: object` to your multipart body `schema`:

```yaml
          multipart/form-data:
            schema:
              type: object    # <------
              required:
              - ...
```